# getAsDataURL() doesn't work in chrome and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="browse" name="browse" size=""  placeholder="Photo" checked="checked" class="upload"/>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:onbrowse()"  class="unknown" value=""/>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
        $(".upload").change(function () {
            var fileObj = $(this).get(0);
            var fileName;
            if (fileObj.files) {
                fileName = fileObj.files.item(0).getAsDataURL()
            } else {
                fileName = fileObj.value;
            }
            $(".unknown").css("background-size", "100px 100px");
            $(".unknown").css("background-image", "url(" + fileName + ")");
        });
    });

    function onbrowse() {
        document.getElementById('browse').click();
    }
```

I have two problems:

1. onclick doesn't work in Chrome and
2. getAsDataURL() doesn't work in Chrome and IE

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does not yet support the File API. Anyhow, you need to use a `FileReader` to read a file. Also, the file is not its file name (your variable naming is a little ambiguous).

The click delegation to the file input works just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/fKQDL/

```
file = fileObj.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader;
fr.onloadend = changeimg;
fr.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: i copy code but it doesn't work and i don't understedn why it dosn't work

Comment: @Aram Mkrtchyan: The fiddle works fine on Chrome for me; so it should work.

Comment: can it be a problem of running script locally?

Comment: @Aram Mkrtchyan: Does the fiddle work for you? You can test it on a local server as well to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much, in a locale works, and my mistake is that.... i put  the script before INPUT but  to be put after the INPUT

Answer (score 1):

Bind the button's behavior with jQuery

```
jQuery('input[type="button"].unknown').click ( onbrowse );
```